# Ansible how to use tasks multiple times in different roles?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have 3 tasks that will get the **version** from the database and I have 3 roles inside these roles few tasks have a dependency on the **version**.

I can't use a variable here because the value is dynamic and I cant set facts because I should be able to run individual roles and only a few tasks from each role with tags.

**My Example below.**

**Role1:-**

*Tasks I need to run multiple times(example):-*

```
- name: get version
  block:
    - command: "mongo get_version.js" 
      register: op
    - name: filter version number from output 
      shell: "echo {{ present_version.stdout }}| grep 'version'"
      register: present_version
  tags: role1_db_tag

- name: do something

- name: do something when a version is something
  when: present_version == "something"
  tags: role1_db_tag
```

**Role2:**

```
- name: get version
  block:
    - command: "mongo get_version.js" 
      register: op
    - name: filter version number from output 
      shell: "echo {{ present_version.stdout }}| grep 'version'"
      register: present_version
  tags: role2_db_tag

- name: do some other things

- name: do something else when a version is something
  when: present_version == "something"
  tags: role2_db_tag
```

Now I am running the get version tasks 3 times in each role now.
Is there any way like handlers just to mention some name for these repetitive tasks and call when required?

**Expecting:-**

**Role2:**

```
- name: fetch version
  function: get_version 
  register: present_version 
  tags: role1_db_tag

- name: do something else when a version is something
  when: present_version == "something"
  tags: role2_db_tag
```

**PS:** Is there a better way than include_* or import_*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have already surmised, the way you would typically handle this is by moving the `get version` task into a separate role, and then including that in the dependent roles using e.g. `import_role`:

```
- import_role:
    name: get_version
```

If you have a number of small shared tasks, you can create a "library" role with multiple task files:

```
- import_role:
    name: library
    tasks_from: get_version
```

See "[Using Roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles)" for a discussion of `include_role` vs `import_role`.

---

You can get similar behavior by adding a dependency to your role
instead.  E.g., in Role1, create a file `meta/main.yml` with the
following content:

```
dependencies:
  - get_version
```

This will automatically run the `get_version` role before `role1` any
time you run `role1`.

See "[Using Role Dependencies](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-dependencies)" for more information.

Comment: The second option the ```library``` role seems more suitable and efficient than others. Even though writing 10 plays if have 10 functions is a bit odd and I don't see any better options as well.